# Taskkill with windowtitle filter from scheduled task

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks

Consider the following batch file:

```
taskkill /IM calc.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Rechner" > C:\test.txt 2>&1
```

When I start a calculator (it has the window title *Rechner* in German) and run this batch file, it closes the calculator and writes to `C:\test.txt` that the kill signal has been sent.

When I start a calculator and run this batch file from a scheduled task that runs when I am logged in, it does the same.

When I start a calculator and run this batch file from a scheduled task that runs independent of user log in, the calculator stays open and `C:\test.txt` says that the task to be killed could not be found.

I think this might be because taskkill cannot "see" the window title from its context in the last case. **How can I make it see the window title when called via a login-independent scheduled task?**

Answer (score -1):

Do not use:

`taskkill /IM calc.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Rechner" > C:\test.txt 2>&1`

Use:

`taskkill /IM calc.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne Rechner" > C:\test.txt 2>&1`

Or better yet:

`taskkill /IM calc.exe > C:\test.txt 2>&1`

I will leave it to you to figure why you have to use the following command:

`cmd /c taskkill /im calc.exe > C:\test.txt 2>&1`

Your scheduled task must be run by a user with admin privileges.

These settings when "Run whether user is logged on or not":

Does not matter whether "Do not store" or "Run with highest" is checked or not.

[image: settings]

These settings when "Run only when user is logged on":
"Run with highest" **must** checked.

[image: settings]

Comment: I am very sorry, but every 4 parts of your answer seem just *wrong* to me. I do not use Windows 10. It closes without `/F`. It *is* calc.exe. It works outside the scheduled task, so it has to be a scheduled task problem. :-(

Comment: @bow More info2.

Comment: Why are you leaving out the /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Rechner" now? The whole question is about that filter not working.

Comment: The filter does work.  You are just using it wrong.  `ne` not `eq`

Comment: *Filter for `calc.exe` that does **not** have the title "Rechner"*?

Comment: What is the result of `cmd /c taskkill /im calc.exe > C:\test.txt 2>&1`